# Shared libraries on Windows - dependencies using wrong dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries, lib

I have a C++ code that uses gdal as library. Compiled with intel c++ compiler 16 on visual studio 2013.

In the configuration, I specify the gdal library path and library file to link with:

**Additional Library Directories: C:\OSGeo4W64\lib   (where gdal_i.lib is)**

**Additional Dependencies: gdal_i.lib**

It used to work a few months ago, but something must have changed in my system. Now, when I try my executable, I get a popup with error:

**The ordinal 361 could not be located in the dynamic link library SSLEAY32.dll**

I can fix it by copying the SSLEAY32.dll from the gdal folder in the executable folder or by removing any call to gdal from my code, but I would like to fix my system rather. How to tell Windows to look in the right directory (I played with the PATH a lot with no success).

Using Dependency Walker, it seems that the gdal.dll is not the one from my OSGEO path, but is taken from my miniconda install. Is there a clean way to fix it? I though that if a library had its dependencies in the same folder, those ones would be used.

[image: Dependency Walker screenshot]

**EDIT**: Solution, thanks to Naidu's answer:

add *C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;* at the beginning of my path, such that the correct gdal202.dll is used in priority.

**but** now python does not start anymore, because it is not selecting its own gdal libraries in the miniconda folder but rather in OSGeo4W64... I can get one or the other working with the same path but not both

**solution** place first in the PATH the directory of Miniconda python executable, then OSGeo4W64 libraries path, then Miniconda libraries path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Additional Library Directories* will helps in only for looking up the .lib (static libraries) files, but not for DLLs.

The DLLs are looked up as shown in the order in below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx

So now, if your intended DLL is to be picked up, then place the DLL in any of the locations in first 4 steps said in above link..... or you can edit the PATH variable of **user variables** of **Environment variables**, with your DLL location.

Because

> User variables take precedence over system environment variables. The
>   user path is appended to the system path.